# How to use the microsoft word to set a ruler that the text on the left-aside will right-align, and the text on the right-aside will left-align?

Tags: microsoft-word

I'd like to use microsoft word to align some text with a strange requirement: the text on the left-aside will right-align, and the text on the right-aside will left-align?

Here is what it should look like:

```
Ruler
          11111111112         3         4
01234567890123456789012345678901234567890

Text
   Country:USA        CountryCode:01
 President:XXX

   Country:Austria    CountryCode:YY
 President:YYY
```

As the above example shows:

- The `:` should always at ruler position `10` and `33` only;
- The text before `:` should right-align and the text after `:` should left-align.

Please don't use any table solution, only **tab stop** and some other technique is required.

Answer (score 0):

### You can use a Table or left-and right- tabs.

See my page: [Justification / Alignment of Text in Word](https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/justification.htm), in particular [Left and Right Justification at the same time](https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/justification.htm#Flush).

If you set a **right-tab** followed almost immediately by a left tab, you could simply use the tab key to align to the right. Then press tab to align the following text to the left. Pressing the tab key tells Word that you now want to type on the right-aligned or left-aligned. The following is from the page I linked above.

> [image: screenshot showing ruler]

Here is a screenshot using your data.

[image: screenshot]

Note the pairs of Right-Tab/Left-Tab set in the ruler. Note also that this is done with a mono-spaced font.

See also:

- [Use Tabs and Tables to Arrange Text](https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/4UseTablesTabs.htm) by Shauna Kelly and
- [Setting Tabs](http://wordfaqs.ssbarnhill.com/SettingTabs.htm) by Suzanne Barnhill